# Login Unsuccessful Not showing

Tags: php, html

I have a login form that will give an error if the username and password is incorrect and display index.php if its successful. Now the successful login works fine. But the message if there is an error is not appearing. Just shows a blank page.

P.S. How would i force a page to go through the login page before accessing it?

My connectivity.php code:

```php
<?php 
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); 
define('DB_NAME', 'list'); 
define('DB_USER','root'); 
define('DB_PASSWORD','****');

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 
/* 
$ID = $_POST['user']; 
$Password = $_POST['pass']; 
*/
function SignIn() 
{ 
    session_start(); 
    if(!empty($_POST['user'])) 
    { 
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM UserName where userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'") or die(mysql_error()); 
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
        if(!empty($row['userName']) AND !empty($row['pass'])) 
        { 
            $_SESSION['userName'] = $row['pass']; 
            header("Location: index.php");

        } 

        else 
        {
            echo "SORRY... YOU ENTERD WRONG ID AND PASSWORD... PLEASE RETRY...";
        } 
    }  

}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 

{ 
    SignIn(); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Switch over to `mysqli_*` OR `PDO` along with prepared statements. You are using very old (deprecated+removed libraray)

Comment: will do @anant sir

Comment: Prepared statements will also fix your issue. You currently have a problem with Array-Accessing inside a String. In PHP it would be done like so: `"string.. ${array['key']} more string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. in the line:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

I removed the "or die" part of the code because when the username or password is wrong the $row has nothing to show so it terminates and doesn't get a chance to go to the the else statement.

Code is working now! Thank you everyone

Answer (score -1):

This is suppposed to be a comment, but i have a low reputation here.

Before i answer your question, please do not use the mysql functions as its no longer supported . Consider a switch to either MYSQLI or PDO. Also, do not trust user input. Meaning do not directly post field values from your form to your database as an attcker can easily exploit it by adding funny javascripts or worse.

```php
<?php
    if (!empty($row['userName']) && ! empty($row['pass'])) {
        $_SESSION['userName'] = $row['pass'];
        header("Location: index.php");
    } else {
        $error[] = "SORRY... YOU ENTERD WRONG ID AND PASSWORD... PLEASE RETRY...";
    }
```

Then add the following code in your form to display the errors

```
<?php
     if (isset($error)) {
        foreach ($error as $validationErrors) {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" align="center">' . $validationErrors . '</div>';
        }
    }
?>
```

FYI: you will need bootstrap to display the errors on the page. I just added that as an extra. Let me know if it works for you

Comment: Why would you add a whole Fronted-Library for simply outputting an error? Also you've just adjusted his code but not changed how it works. Simply replacing "AND" with `&&` does NOT fix this code.